# Getting 404 error accessing a cake application

Tags: cakephp

I had a working cake application that I tar'd up and sent to someone to do some development work on, and now they've sent it back to me. I've put the files under the root folder of my webserver. I can successfully get to the root level index.php page (http://localhost/newcake/index.php) but when I try to access the user information (http://localhost/newcake/users) I get a 404 error. That url worked in my old cake instance. I'm wondering if the developer remapped the url paths somehow in the cake app and if so, where do I go to find that?

Note: I'd ask the developer this question but they're not available right now and I'd like to get this resolved as soon as possible.

Update: I did a search for .htaccess files under the new application and found the following:

```
./.htaccess
./app/.htaccess
./app/webroot/.htaccess
./cake/console/templates/skel/.htaccess
./cake/console/templates/skel/webroot/.htaccess
```

I checked the locations and the contents with the original application and it all appears to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the file permissions. Check also that you have the .htaccess files in the right places. Some operating systems - Ubuntu in particular - will copy files in a folder but omit the dot files.

If they're missing, transplant them from a clean install.

Also, see here for the .htaccess files and where to put them: http://book.cakephp.org/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

Comment: The file permissions on the cache directory were an issue initially but I corrected that, and I even opened up the permissions on all the files in the entire cake application. Checking the .htaccess files now...

Comment: That was it. I had to add an "AllowOverride" entry for that directory to httpd.conf. Thanks!